# "unknown authentication strategy" "jwt"

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm now retired and now have some time to learn how to develop an MEVN application ;-) I'm now in the point of securing a few pages in the app with a `jwt` token.
I can log a user and later read its token:

```
app.get('/movies', (req,res) => {
    jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
     console.log(Version + 'JWT token: ' + jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest(req));
    Movie.find({}, 'name description release_year genre', (error, movies) => {
        if(error) { console.log(error);}
        console.log(Version + "Fetched " + movies.length + " movies");
        res.send(movies);
    });
});
```

I get the user token in the console. Fine! This get request is not yet protected. 
To protect it I modify slightly the 1st line:

```
app.get('/movies', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req,res) => {
...
```

An error is now triggered.

> Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"

After reading a few million questions and answers on various sites, I'm short of any idea to fix my problem.
Suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you instructed passport with what `jwt` is? You need something like `passport.use(new JwtStrategy(options))` https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt

Comment: No. I just tested your suggestion.

Comment: The JwtStrategy callback ( with payload and done ) is not called ;-(

Comment: First, make sure you added `passport.initialize()` middleware. Then check you have called `passport.use` before declaring `/movies` route. BTW docs :) http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40670855/4209887 refer to this answer

Answer (score 1):

check your server.js or index.js. Add these initializer.

```
const passport = require('passport');
// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);
```